Angular HttpClient calls and signals
I am diving deep into signals watching tutorials and reading articles. When calling an api endpoint with httpClient I've seen two main approaches (at least that I liked) and I am unable to find much online that compares the two. The first one is to have a service with a function that makes the endpoint call with httpClient, handles errors with RxJs operators, then the response is transformed into a signal. The calling component gets back the response as a signal. So basically transforming the response into a signal and error handling is done by the service. The second approach is to have the service make the endpoint call with httpClient in a function that uses async/await and returns a promise. The calling component will also have an async await function with a try-catch block, this function gets the promise and sets the response to a signal. So basically the service just gets the data and sends it to the caller as a promise, the calling component handles the errors and assigns the data to a signal. Thoughts? Ideas? comments? mix both? other approaches?

I think you are mixing two questions together: 1) which technology to use - observable or promise? I would say, in angular, always use observables because it's mich easier to read and much more customisable in behavior. 2) who is doing the error handling -The caller or the service? I believe that depends. Is the error recoverable? Then the caller might recover from it or just ignore it. If the result is optional, just returning empty in an error case might be feasible. It depends.

This question comes from trying to migrate my apps to angular 18 where angular is trying to stay away from observables. The angular team is recommending to use little to no observables. Although there are more strategies to calling endpoints than just httpClient, I do believe its the most effective one and it returns an observable so then I could still use rxjs operators to handle the error. I'm curious about what others think what's the best approach on handling, specifically, errors coming from APIs with all the major angular updates. I'm already handling other errors without observables

I also think observables, for the most part, are not easier to read as one the drawbacks of rxjs is its learning curve. But I do agree that observables are more customizable. Btw, I am leaning towards handling the api errors in the service with observable operators but just wanted to be clear why I'm asking the question

Did you end up handling the errors in the service? Kinda makes sense, handling the error as close to the source as possible

@remi I am handling errors in the service with rxjs operators. Then I am returning the results as a signal when there are no errors

Angular uses httpClient and all methods are going to return an observable, then unless you have a specific purpose to use a promise (For Eg: the sequence that uses the service call requires a promise to be returned) There is no big benefit by converting the observable to a promise.
Promise does not have easy error handling and promise switching is possible, but from an angular perspective stream using pipe is much more effecient and can handle any scenarios you need.
